# What is Websockets' net.connect().write()?

Tags: node.js, websocket

For example if I have `var remote = net.connect(); remote.write(data) && ...` I can get a boolean indicating if remote is writing data, so if I have:

```
var remote = new WebSocket('???', {
  protocol: 'binary'
});
```

How do I know if remote is writing data?

Comment: Which websocket library are you using?

Comment: @jfriend00 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

Comment: Keep in mind that the WebSocket protocol is built on top of the TCP socket protocol. WebSockets format their data in a particular way that TCP sockets are not restricted to. Just letting you know in case you weren't aware.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any documented way to do what you're talking about so you have to look into the [source code](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocket.js) for your library and see what you can find.

First off, the webSocket class itself, is an `EventEmitter` and contains a property named `_socket` that is the actual TCP socket.  So you can get access to that directly if you have to.

That `_socket` property is initialized [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocket.js#L715).

The `send()` method is defined [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocket.js#L352).  The first thing you will see is that it doesn't have any return value so it certainly doesn't return what you were getting from `remote.write()`.  Instead, the sending logic is implemented in a `Sender` object [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/Sender.js#L253) which after constructing the right frame format, ultimately calls `sendFrame()` [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/Sender.js#L372).  There you can see the actual socket writes:

```
sendFrame (list, cb) {
    if (list.length === 2) {
      this._socket.write(list[0]);
      this._socket.write(list[1], cb);
    } else {
      this._socket.write(list[0], cb);
    }
  }
```

And, you can see that the return value from `socket.write()` is ignored so it is not available without modifying the library's code.

I don't honestly see any way to know when the write buffer is full here.  There's a `drain` event on the socket object that will tell you when the write buffer was full and is no longer full and you could listen for that, but I don't see any supported way to know when it becomes full.  I guess one thing you could do is from the outside is to override the `_socket.write()` method and emit your own event to the webSocket object when the buffer gets full.

It seems like the cleanest fix would be to make a return value from `.send()` that returns the value from `.write()`, but that requires forking the library and modifying the the code in a couple places.

I filed an [issue with the webSocket Github project](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1255) in case we're missing something or in case the author has other ideas for how to deal with this or in case they decide to fix it.

---

It was suggested [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1255) that the way to deal with this issue is to use the callback that can be passed to `ws.send(data, callback)` and that callback will be called when the data is actually sent.  This is not exactly what you asked for, but is what was suggested in [the issue I filed on Github](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1255) for handling your original question.

Comment: @AeroWang - Added note at the end of my answer based on feedback to the Github issue I filed.